# How to extract the response using a regular expression for Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How can I extract the response using a regular expression for Jmeter.

Jmeter is not extracting the response item that I want to extract. I've tried several times, but I failed. How can I extract the response item?

Response data is as shown in the screenshot:

The value which I need to extract has been highlighted.

I tried extracting using the following expression, but it failed:

```
<h2>.+?<a hfref="http://(.+?)">.+?</a>.</h2>
```

Comment: Please use this syntax `\?Id\=(.+?)&` which will retrieve the ID as mentioned in your screenshot. You need to add escape characters to your syntax. Let me if this works for you.

Comment: Answer you have mentioned is working - \?id\=(.+?)&

Comment: I have posted an another question below of this page.could you please solve that too.it would be great help

Comment: I Accepted,All i need to do ic click on the tick right.anything else i have to do.Once i refrsh the page the tick is getting removed

Comment: @NaveenKumar ,Yes i have accepted the best solution given by you.Could you please  clear my second query.it would be of great help

Comment: I have posted the question in the following link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43840568/how-to-extract-using-regular-expression-if-there-are-multiple-variables-in-jmete

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please check and accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to extract the `Id` value.

In your `Regular Expression Extractor`, configure below details. Use the regular expression as `Public/FormsPreview.aspx\?Id\=(.+?)&` to retrieve the `Id`.

You can use other unique left/right boundaries as well, as your regular expression.

[image: Reg Ex Config]

### How to validate your regular expression extractor?

1. To validate your regular expression extractor, add a `Debug Sampler` (Right Click on your thread group > `Add > Sampler > Debug Sampler`)
2. Execute the test plan
3. In `View Results Tree` you can see the `c_ID` value as shown below.

[image: Reg Ex Output]

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how vary can result be *(I mean, how the form is changing? is that only querystring Id parameter that is different? could there be another response (than Object Moved) with Id that you don't want to parse? etc.)*, the regular expression in the Regular Expession Extractor Post-Processor (which fits best here) would be different.

From simplest context-agnostic, `Id=(\d+)` (that is considering you have numeric Id), to making it case-insensitive `(?i)Id=(\d+)` and/or alphanumeric `Id=([0-9a-zA-Z]+)`, or even whatever symbols are in (but you'd be forced to start to include context in this case ) `Id=(.+?)&` - and up to one that uses broader context evaluating the whole multiline stuff, like `(?im)<title>Object\smoved</title>.+<a\shref=.+Id=(\d+)`

And don't forget to use `$1$` as your Template and take the Match 1.

I suggest you to stick to the most narrow and most context-agnostic one you can afford (the very first example here). 
Add some assertions to make sure you're on the right page - despite the fact they executed after post-processors, you'd see something is wrong, at least.

Answer (score -1):

You can add regular expression extractor like following
[image]

Comment: I tried this expression ,unfortunately.its not working .id=(.+?)

Comment: @paulbaboo please use this syntax `\?Id\=(.+?)&`