# How to Extract using regular expression if there are multiple variables in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

How to Extract using regular expression  if there are multiple variables in Jmeter

Steps:

1. I have an URL where there are 2 variables.i would like to extract the second variable ie"communityID".can anyone please help on the regular expression that i should use in jmeter to extract that variable

Screenshot has been attached
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZhId.jpg)

Comment: use regular expression as `FormsPreview.aspx\?Id\=(.+?)&amp;name\=Newform\&amp\;Community\=(.+?)&amp`. In the group add `$1$$2$`. Now use `c_ID_g1` for the `Id` and `c_ID_g2` for the `Community`. Replace `c_Id` with your `Reference Name`. Let me know if this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the below configuration for your `Regular Expression Extractor`. This will extract two values and store it in the `<your-reference-name>_g1` and `<your-reference-name>_g2` respectively.

**Regular Expression** as

`Public/FormsPreview.aspx\?Id\=(.+?)\&amp\;name\=Newform\&amp\;Community\=(.+?)\&`

**Template** as

`$1$$2$`

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

### How to validate your regular expression extractor?

1. To validate your regular expression extractor, add a `Debug Sampler` (Right Click on your thread group > `Add > Sampler > Debug Sampler`)
2. Execute the test plan
3. In `View Results Tree` you can see the `c_ID_g1` and `c_ID_2` value as shown below.

You can use these variables in the test plan using this syntax `${c_ID_g1}` and `${c_ID_2}`

[image: Output]